# Error when trying to decode json: simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, django, api, python-3.8

I'm receiving this error when trying to decode json:

**simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Any help will be appreciated.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def home(request):
    response = requests.get('https://dev-api.prime.com/api/v1/hub/login')
    data = response.json()
    return render (request, 'home.html', {
        'email': data['email'],
        'password': data['password']
    })
```

urls.py:

```
 path ('home/', views.home, name="home"),
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>API</h2>
  <p>Your email is <strong>{{ email }}</strong>, and password <strong>{{ password }}</strong></p>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to send POST request from the terminal:

```
http POST https://dev-api.prime.com/api/v1/hub/login email="sssdprime@gmail.com" password="asssdps"
```

and get the response I was looking for:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 866
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2020 07:09:45 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Set-Cookie: _language=811f45dc7836f8b3da4c5d04b177501191c20a3f77a46812f864a3bca7d5d3e1a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A9%3A%22_language%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A2%3A%22en%22%3B%7D; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: _csrf=5f3fb0e6b529660e0a11a97a3fd3e9a85aa3794d20; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept
X-Debug-Duration: 816
X-Debug-Link: /debug/default/view?tag=5f991938b8410
X-Debug-Tag: 5f991938b8410
X-Frame-Option: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.18
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection: 1

{
    "data": {
        "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MDM4Njg5ODUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2Rldi1hcGkuZGVudGFwcmltZS5jb206ODA5NCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2Rldi1hcGkuZGVudGFwcmltZS5jb206ODA58",
        "complete": false,
        "country": "AL",
        "date_of_birth": null,
        "email": "sssdprime@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "somename",
        "id": 201,
        "last_name": "somename",
        "phone": "08865444567",
        "role": 10,
        "sf_token": "0014H00002dd",
        "type_language": "en",
        "username": ""
    },
    "status": 200,
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: response = requests.get('https://dev-api.prime.com/api/v1/hub/login')
Did you make sure this line of code actually return something?

Comment: @Alviandoh yes, I tried to send post request from the terminal, and it returns the correct response

Comment: please put your the response too, it might help.

Comment: @Alviandoh It returns the correct credentials for this user. Like email, password, phone, access token and etc. I'm not sure how this can help. Pretty long json response.

Comment: I'm highly certain this error is caused by no response was given from the url. Did you make sure that  1. you use correct method (POST/GET) 2.  no typo in URL?

Comment: @Alviandoh of course. I edit my question. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your request

```
http POST https://dev-api.prime.com/api/v1/hub/login email="sssdprime@gmail.com" password="asssdps"
```

While in code,

```
response = requests.get('https://dev-api.prime.com/api/v1/hub/login')
```

They are different. In the first request you used "POST" method, with email and password alongside it.
While in your code, you simply ask for "GET" method.

Change request code to something like this, and it should be receiving the correct response.

```
response = requests.post('https://dev-api.prime.com/api/v1/hub/login', json={"email":"sssdprime@gmail.com", "password":"asssdps"})
```

and Since the response you want is something like this

```
{
    "data": {
        ...
    },
    "status": 200,
    "success": true
}
```

The response will return dictionary. And you only want the data. You need to access the value inside "data" key. So change this,

```
data = response.json()
```

into,

```
data = response.json()['data']
```

Comment: I got KeyError at /home/ 'email'. What is this for? For my home func in views.py.

Comment: ah also I forgot about that, I'll be addressing that one in my edit

Comment: @pythondeveloper should be addressed with the newest edit with some explanation.